# Register dll/tlb

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, registry, arcgis, typelib

I'm attempting to register a GIS based dll on a test computer and I'm having problems loading in the tlb file with ArcGIS 9.3.1 - ArcMap  on the test computer.  When I attempt to load the tlb file is says **"No New Objects Added"**.  I created the dll file using Visual Studio 2010.  The tlb file loads fine on my developer computer.  I'm registering the dll/tlb on the test computer by using cmd.exe command (see below).

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe C:\Temp\My.dll /tlb:My.tlb/codebase
```

The registration replies as successful and the item is listed in the Component Category under the MX Commands category.  Below is the COM GUIDs portion code that I'm using within my class.

```
#Region "COM GUIDs"
    Public Const ClassId As String = "1bf94bdf-907c-4026-816f-50feb7a2a976"
    Public Const InterfaceId As String = "7ba8a4d5-d15c-4d95-a819-a3e7cbe84533"
    Public Const EventsId As String = "2ab51582-47e1-490c-899d-a80992c20fdf"
#End Region
```

**The OS of the developer computer is:**

Microsoft Windows XP 32bit,
Version 5.1 - Service Pack 3

AND

**The OS of the test computer is:**

Microsoft Windows XP 64bit,
Version 5.2 - Service Pack 2

Do I need to do a Windows Update on the developer computer (to 5.2) or is there something wrong in my dll/tlb registration method?

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE:**

The ArcGIS software on the test computer is installed under the C:\Program Files (x86) location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to register it using the 64-bit version of RegASM on your target PC. You should find it in:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727
                                  ^^
```

Note that I'm assuming that you have compiled your code to MSIL (by selecting `AnyCPU` as the platform). If you have compiled it to target `32-bit`, then you will need to change that.

This is because a 64-bit process cannot find registrations performed by the 32-bit version of RegAsm, and vice-versa.

Comment: the target CPU was set to AnyCPU.  I tried your "Framework64" path.  It registered it, but when I looked for it in the Component Category it was not listed, whereas the "Framework" path option did list it in the Component Category.  The test computer has two Program Files folders under the C: drive ("Program Files", and "Program Files (x86)".  The ArcGIS software is located under the Program Files (x86) folder.

Comment: @artwork21 The ArcGIS software is 32-bit in that case, so my answer doesn't apply. I'll leave it here as it's a common problem.

Comment: should I do a Windows update on the developer computer to upgrade the service pack to 5.2? Thanks!

Comment: @artwork21 There isn't a windows update to update to 5.2. Windows XP (32-bit) **is** 5.1. You have `Service Pack 3` which means you have the latest version.